# Using layout in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

I am working on a cms, and have the need for dynamic template choice in the pages controller. I have a before filter that grabs the chosen template name in the user settings. Now I need to figure out how to render the correct layout using that instance variable.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#This sets @template to the template object. @template.name is "Default"
before_filter :get_template

layout "templates/#{@template.name.downcase.gsub(" ", "_")}"
#layout "templates/default" #This line renders fine
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

My guess is that the before_filter doesn't necessarily run 'before' the template is called.

Is there a better way that I should be trying to accomplish this?  I do not really have experience in using many templates and choosing which one to render.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def template_path
    #... returns the template path, e.g. "layouts/theme_a"
  end

  def set_template
    self.class.layout(template_path)
  end

  before_filter :set_template

end
```

Comment: While both of your methods seems to be good, I am choosing this one because I really don't want to load the template object on every controller when I know I will never need it anywhere but pages controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    get_template inside of application controller , so we can access from any controlller :

    --------------------
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    @template=get_template
    layout "templates/#{@template.name.downcase.gsub(" ", "_")}"
end
```

Comment: unfortunately I only want this to apply to one controller. I've got a public site that has its own template (just using the application layout), and a pages controller that needs the dynamic template. You did give me an idea though. if I get template in application controller, then it should be available by the time I call layout in the pages controller. I'll give that a shot, thanks

Comment: Apllication controller is parent cotroller of all controller ,

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout :set_custom_layout


  def set_custom_layout
    get_template
  end
end
```